# currently my sharepoint 2016 farm build version is 16.0.4327.1000

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, patching

currently my SharePoint 2016 farm build version is 16.0.4327.1000.Can you please suggest me which patch do I need to install to get latest version farm build version

Answer (score 1):

**Oh,** Your build number refers to the **`SharePoint Server 2016 Release Candidate`** that **not** supported to be upgraded to RTM!

> **Note:** In some rare cases, you may installed RTM but it shows the RC build number! it's a bug! and in this case, there is no issue to install the latest CU update.

**So** if you are sure you already installed the RTM version but it shows RC build number, go ahead to install the latest CU.

**Otherwise,** The available solution is to download and install a fresh the [Sharepoint Server 2016 RTM](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51493). **but** you can't upgrade your current RC farm to RTM farm.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, we can install pu for SharePoint Server 2016 Release Candidate.

To get latest version farm build version, you need to install November 2018 Patch.

You can download November 2018 Patch (Language Independent Files) from here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57534

Besides, SharePoint 2016 Builds List for your reference:

https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Builds/SharePoint-2016-Builds.aspx